# Easy way to write below arrow (\arrow{-U>}) in chemfig?

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I have been using chemfig for a while and I like it very much. But some small things I still can't do. Check this example:

```
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{[2]OH-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}{Glycerol} 
\hspace{.3cm}
\arrow{-U>[\footnotesize ATP][\footnotesize ADP + H$^{+}$][][0.6][45]}
\hspace{.7cm}
\chemname{\chemfig{[2]O(-[0]\circleatom{P})-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}{Glycerol 3-phosphate} 
\schemestop
```

I would like to write the enzyme's name (glycerol kinase) below the U-shaped arrow. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, indicate what packages you're using for typesetting the chemical formulas.

Comment: I think a MWE here would be something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
A \arrow{-U>[X][Y]} B
\schemestop
\end{document}`, where without the `U` the `Y` text would appear under the arrow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing the `\circleatom` is a copy of [what I used here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50868/5049). I vaguely remembered having defined something like it before.

The middle of an `-U>` arrow is a node named `Uarrow@arctangent`. If you have only one such arrow you can use that fact to write something beneath it with `\chemmove`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw]{\printatom{#1}};}

\begin{document}

\setarrowoffset{1cm}
\schemestart
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{[2]OH-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}
    {Glycerol} 
  \arrow{-U>[\footnotesize ATP]%
            [\footnotesize ADP + H$^{+}$]%
            []%
            [.25]}[,3]
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{[2]O(-[0]\circleatom{P})-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}
    {Glycerol 3-phosphate} 
\schemestop
\makeatletter
  \chemmove{\node[below] at (Uarrow@arctangent) {below}; }
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need that more often you should consider usings `chemfig`'s possibility to add new arrow types. You could for example adapt the definition of the `-U>` arrow to define a variant that takes a third argument:

```
\makeatletter
% define an arrow type `-y>' that takes 6 optional arguments
% \arrow{-y>[<label arc start>]%
%           [<label arc end>]%
%           [<label below>]%
%           [<arrow shift>]%
%           [<ratio arc radius/arrow length>]% default: 0.333
%           [<half of angle of arc>]% default: 60
\definearrow{6}{-y>}{%
    % shift the arrow:
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#4}%
    % draw main arrow:
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full]
      (\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](yarrow@arctangent){};%
    % draw first half of arc if label #1 is given:
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\ifx\@empty#1\@empty[draw=none]\fi}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (yarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[
          radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#5\@empty0.333\else#5\fi,
          start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,
          delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#6\@empty60\else#6\fi]
        node(yarrow@start){};
    % draw second half of arrow if label #2 is given:
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#2\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF@full]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (yarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[
          radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#5\@empty0.333\else#5\fi,
          start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
          delta angle=\ifx\@empty#6\@empty60\else#6\fi]
        node(yarrow@end){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#4.}\@nil-\else+\fi}%
    % place labels #1 and #2:
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{yarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{yarrow@end}%
    % place label #3:
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node
}
\makeatother
```

It can now be used as follows:

```
\schemestart
 A
 \arrow{-y>[a][b][below]}
 B
\schemestop
```

[image]

It has three further optional arguments which are the same as the ones of `-U>`.

---

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand*\circleatom[1]{\tikz\node[circle,draw]{\printatom{#1}};}


\makeatletter
% define an arrow type `-y>' that takes 6 optional arguments
% \arrow{-y>[<label arc start>]%
%           [<label arc end>]%
%           [<label below>]%
%           [<arrow shift>]%
%           [<ratio arc radius/arrow length>]% default: 0.333
%           [<half of angle of arc>]% default: 60
\definearrow{6}{-y>}{%
    % shift the arrow:
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#4}%
    % draw main arrow:
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full]
      (\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](yarrow@arctangent){};%
    % draw first half of arc if label #1 is given:
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\ifx\@empty#1\@empty[draw=none]\fi}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (yarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[
          radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#5\@empty0.333\else#5\fi,
          start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,
          delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#6\@empty60\else#6\fi]
        node(yarrow@start){};
    % draw second half of arrow if label #2 is given:
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#2\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF@full]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (yarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[
          radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#5\@empty0.333\else#5\fi,
          start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
          delta angle=\ifx\@empty#6\@empty60\else#6\fi]
        node(yarrow@end){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#4.}\@nil-\else+\fi}%
    % place labels #1 and #2:
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{yarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{yarrow@end}%
    % place label #3:
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setarrowoffset{1cm}
\schemestart
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{[2]OH-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}
    {Glycerol} 
  \arrow{-y>[\footnotesize ATP]%
            [\footnotesize ADP + H$^{+}$]%
            [below]%
            []%
            [.25]}[,3]
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{[2]O(-[0]\circleatom{P})-[4]CH_2-CH(-[0]OH)-CH_2(-[0]OH)}}
    {Glycerol 3-phosphate} 
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey cgnieder, 

ideed, I have "borrowed" your \circleatom and I appreciate very much your effort maintaining all these packages.

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @bispo you're welcome! BTW: I _don't_ maintain `chemfig` (nor could I). All credits go to Christian Tellechea (@unbonpetit).

Comment: @clemens Used your code and got an error message: Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'CF@full'. [.25]}[,3]

Comment: @Sam replace `CF@full` with `CF` – `chemfig` changed its arrow tips some while ago…

Answer (score 9):

Here's an update on @runiq's extension to @clemens' code above (and partially an extension of my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370497/117534)), that is compatible with current versions of `chemfig` **(as of 2017, v1.2e)**, for an all-powerful `-X>` arrow that can label above, below and midway along the arrow.

[image: looks the same, i know..]

The output looks the same, but there has been a few under the hood changes, described below.

But first...

### Quick Intro on how to use

The syntax is similar to the original `-U>` arrow, and (obviously) identical to that of @runiq's `-X>` arrow.

```
\arrow{-X>[#1][#2][#3][#4][#5][#6][#7][#8][#9]}
```

where arguments are:

- `[#1]`: Label to be placed at top arrow (start)
- `[#2]`: Label to be placed at top arrow (end)
- `[#3]`: Label to be placed at top arrow (midway)
- `[#4]`: Label to be placed at bottom arrow (start)
- `[#5]`: Label to be placed at bottom arrow (end)
- `[#6]`: Label to be placed at bottom arrow (midway)
- `[#7]`: Y-shift for the arrow, positive for upwards shift, vice versa
- `[#8]`: Radius of arc (default 0.333)
- `[#9]`: Angle for arc (default 60)

---

### What has changed from @runiq's answer

- Overall code structure is different. This is based on the `-U>` definition from the `chemfig` documentation.
- The arrow head is given by `-CF`, no longer `-CF@full`, as pointed out in the comments.
- Included `CF@arrow@current@style` as a style when drawing the arrows. In short, this means the default arrow settings will be passed on to the `-X>` arrow. Demonstrated below:

[image: modified vs original]

---

### Code and result

```
\makeatletter
% Arguments:
% #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6: Labels as shown in the output figure
% #7: yshift for the arrow, positive for upwards shift, vice versa
% #8: radius of arc (default 0.333)
% #9: angle for arc (default 60)
\definearrow9{-X>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#7}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](Xarrow@arctangent){};%
    \CF@ifempty{#8}
    {\def\CF@Xarrow@radius{0.333}}
    {\def\CF@Xarrow@radius{#8}}%
    \CF@ifempty{#9}%
    {\def\CF@Xarrow@absangle{60}}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF@Xarrow@absangle{abs(#9)}}
    % Draw top arrow (start)
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Xarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,delta angle=-\CF@Xarrow@absangle]node(Xarrow1@start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Xarrow@radius,%
    start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF@Xarrow@absangle]%
    node(Xarrow1@end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start)
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Xarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,delta angle=\CF@Xarrow@absangle]node(Xarrow2@start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Xarrow@radius,%
    start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF@Xarrow@absangle]%
    node(Xarrow2@end){};
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@stra{\CF@Xarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@strb{\CF@Xarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \ifdim\CF@Xarrow@radius pt>\z@
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@stra{Xarrow1@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@stra{Xarrow1@end}%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#4}{0}\CF@tmp@strb{Xarrow2@start}{#5}{1}\CF@tmp@strb{Xarrow2@end}%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}\CF@tmp@stra\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#6}{0.5}\CF@tmp@strb\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
    \else
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#2}{0}\CF@tmp@stra{Xarrow1@start}{#1}{1}\CF@tmp@stra{Xarrow1@end}%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#5}{0}\CF@tmp@strb{Xarrow2@start}{#4}{1}\CF@tmp@strb{Xarrow2@end}%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}\CF@tmp@stra\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#6}{0.5}\CF@tmp@strb\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

With the above code placed in the preamble, the code below produces the following output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
% <paste def. of -X> here>
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \schemestart
    A
    \arrow{-X>[1][2][3][4][5][6][][0.333][60]}
    B
    \arrow{-X>[][2][][4][][][5pt][0.5][70]}% Note the yshift, radius and angle changes
    C
    \schemestop
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: final]

---

### Bugs?

Unfortunately, setting the radius (argument #8) as negative would flip the two `U` arrows horizontally (i.e. they point from B to A), but the straight arrow will still point from A to B. As it stands, I don't see a way to fix this, barring a complete re-definition, or a definition of an alternate, reversed `-X>` arrow.

Comment: What if I need an equilibrium arrow plus curved arrows? Should be easy, but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: @Viridjan Hi, please [ask a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and provide a clear description of what you would like there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for updating my hacky arrow thing. That was the first time I've ever written LaTeX code (and it'll probably be the last time, too). :-)

Comment: As of V. 1.4 of ChemFig, this solution does not work as the syntax for using internal ChemFig functions was changed. I have made a re-write of this code that you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/f7KraMJr)

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** Please see Troy's answer for an updated version of this command that works with more recent versions of chemfig.

---

I've recently had to use a similar kind of arrow and decided to expand on @cgnieder's `-y>` arrow:

```
\makeatletter
% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
\definearrow9{-X>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#7}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](Xarrow@arctangent){};%
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\ifx\@empty#1\@empty[draw=none]\fi}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
        delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow1@start){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#2\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF@full]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,%
        delta angle=\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow1@end){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\ifx\@empty#4\@empty[draw=none]\fi}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
        delta angle=\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow2@start){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\ifx\@empty#5\@empty draw=none,\fi-CF@full]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Xarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\ifx\@empty#8\@empty0.333\else#8\fi,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
        delta angle=-\ifx\@empty#9\@empty60\else#9\fi]node(Xarrow2@end){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#7.}\@nil-\else+\fi}%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow1@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow1@end}%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0.5}\CF@tmp@str\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{\if\string-\expandafter\@car\detokenize{#7.}\@nil+\else-\fi}%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#4}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow2@start}{#5}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Xarrow2@end}%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#6}{0.5}\CF@tmp@str\CF@arrow@start@node{}{}{}\CF@arrow@end@node%
}
\makeatother
```

The `-X>` arrow has 9 optional arguments. The first three are similar to those for `-y>`, but all of them are *above* the arrow. The 4th to 6th are similar but below the arrow. The 7th to 9th are the usual vertical shift, length coefficient, and half-angle as per the `-U>` and `-y>` arrows.

The `-X>` arrow looks like this in action:

```
\schemestart
A
\arrow{-X>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
B
\schemestop
```

[image]

Comment: Your code gives me `! Package pgf Error: No shape named e is known.` when one of the optional arguments of the arrow is used.

Comment: @cgnieder: How exactly did you invoke the arrow? I've tried it with an MWE and both pdflatex/lualatex, and everything seems to work. MWE: https://gist.github.com/runiq/6098546

Comment: Just as I said: with the code you provided. I copy-pasted your code, added `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and copy-pasted the scheme in between.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I made an error while copy-pasting. Should be fixed now…

Comment: I get a `Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'CF@full'.`

Comment: @ArchStanton I think the definition changed. Using `CF` instead of `CF@full` works for me

Comment: @Troy I've updated my answer to point to your arrow instead, thanks for taking the time to make this work with newer versions! :)

Answer (score 5):

## Version with Equilibrium and Disequalibrium arrows

Inspired by [Troy's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372947/142008) and [Jasper Habicht's answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456301/142008). Uses same I/O convention as Troy's answer and as the `-U>` arrow from the [ChemFig Documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf).

Addent arrows in the `-X>` arrow defintion are customized according to the PGF arrows documentation. See the [PGFManual](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section 16 for more info on how to customize these.

Compatable with ChemFig 1.41

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\catcode`\_=11
% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
% #7: Optional shift, default 0
% #8: Optional arrow radius
% #9: Optional arrow angle
\definearrow9{-X>}{%
    % handle optional shift
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#7}%
    % handle optional arrow radius
    \CF_ifempty{#8}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{abs{#8}}}%
    % handle optional arrow angle
    \CF_ifempty{#9}%
        {\def\CF_Xarrowabsangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Xarrowabsangle{abs(#9)}}
    % draw basic arrow
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)node[midway](Xarrowarctangent){};%
    \begingroup
    \pgfarrowharpoontrue
    % Draw top arrow (start)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow1start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-{Stealth[left,round,scale=1.1,inset'=0pt 0.55]}]}%angle'=40
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow1end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow2start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-{Stealth[right,round,scale=1.1,inset'=0pt 0.555]}]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow2end){};
    \endgroup
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstra{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstrb{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#2}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#4}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#5}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
}


% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
% #7: Optional shift, default 0
% #8: Optional arrow radius
% #9: Optional arrow angle
\definearrow9{<=X=>}{%
    % handle optional shift
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#7}%
    % handle optional arrow radius
    \CF_ifempty{#8}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{abs{#8}}}%
    % handle optional arrow angle
    \CF_ifempty{#9}%
        {\def\CF_Xarrowabsangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Xarrowabsangle{abs(#9)}}
    % ensure harpoon style lines
    \begingroup
    \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
    % draw equilibrium lines
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1)node[midway](toparrowarctangent){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0)node[midway](bottomarrowarctangent){};%
    % Draw top arrow (start) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (toparrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow1start){};
    % Draw top arrow (end) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (toparrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow1end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (bottomarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow2start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (bottomarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow2end){};
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstra{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstrb{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#2}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#4}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#5}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \endgroup
}


% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
% #7: Optional shift, default 0
% #8: Optional arrow radius
% #9: Optional arrow angle
\definearrow9{<=X=>>}{%
    % handle optional shift
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#7}%
    % handle optional arrow radius
    \CF_ifempty{#8}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{abs{#8}}}%
    % handle optional arrow angle
    \CF_ifempty{#9}%
        {\def\CF_Xarrowabsangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Xarrowabsangle{abs(#9)}}
    % ensure harpoon style lines
    \begingroup
    \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
    % draw equilibrium lines
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0.000,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode f0){}%
            node[pos=0.155,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode r0){}%
            node[pos=1.000,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode f1){}%
            node[pos=0.845,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode r1){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode f0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode f1)node[midway](forarrowarctangent){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode r1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode r0)node[midway](revarrowarctangent){};%
    % Draw top arrow (start) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (forarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow1start){};
    % Draw top arrow (end) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (forarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow1end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (revarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow2start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (revarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow2end){};
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstra{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstrb{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#2}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#4}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#5}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \endgroup
}
% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
% #7: Optional shift, default 0
% #8: Optional arrow radius
% #9: Optional arrow angle
\definearrow9{<<=X=>}{%
    % handle optional shift
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#7}%
    % handle optional arrow radius
    \CF_ifempty{#8}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{abs{#8}}}%
    % handle optional arrow angle
    \CF_ifempty{#9}%
        {\def\CF_Xarrowabsangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Xarrowabsangle{abs(#9)}}
    % ensure harpoon style lines
    \begingroup
    \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
    % draw equilibrium lines
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0.155,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode f0){}%
            node[pos=0.000,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode r0){}%
            node[pos=0.845,yshift= 1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode f1){}%
            node[pos=1.000,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode r1){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode f0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode f1)node[midway](forarrowarctangent){};%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode r1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode r0)node[midway](revarrowarctangent){};%
    % Draw top arrow (start) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (forarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow1start){};
    % Draw top arrow (end) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (forarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow1end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end) (left hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (revarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow2start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start) (right hand side)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (revarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow2end){};
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstra{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstrb{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#2}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#4}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#5}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \endgroup
}

\catcode`\_=8


\begin{document}

\schemestart
A
\arrow{-X>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
B
\schemestop
\schemestart
A
\arrow{<=X=>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
B
\schemestop

\schemestart
Z
\arrow{-X>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
Y
\arrow{<=X=>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
X
\schemestop
\schemestart
A
\arrow{<=X=>>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
B
\arrow{<<=X=>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}
C
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: arrows example]

---

## Note

As of version 1.4 of ChemFig (c. May 2019), the previous answers, are no longer functional as a result of a change in the way that ChemFig handles internal calls. - I have posted un updated version of Troy's code as a comment on his answer

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate the equilibrium arrow by 90°, the distance between the two opposing arrows disappears.

```
\schemestart
   Z
     \arrow{-X>[][2][3][4][][]}
   Y
     \arrow{<=X=>[1][2][3][4][5][6]}[-90,1]
   X
\schemestop
```

[[image]]