# Upside-down -U> arrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'd like to draw something like this:

[image]

The most versatile solution would be something analogous to the `-X>` type arrow defined in "[Easy way to write below arrow (\arrow{-U>}) in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125761/35903)", which gives an error. Another definition I've tried is the one in "[Position label of curved arrow in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370431/position-label-of-curved-arrow-in-chemfig)" but it lacks the tip on the curved arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use the solution from "[Easy way to write below arrow (\arrow{-U>}) in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125761/35903)", you can change `-CF@full` to `-CF` in the definition. That works for me.

---

I have here an adaptation (really trivial) if you would like to use my solution from "[Position label of curved arrow in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370431/position-label-of-curved-arrow-in-chemfig)". I point it out in the code using an arrow in comments.

```
\makeatletter
\definearrow5{-u>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](uarrow@arctangent){};%
    \CF@ifempty{#4}
    {\def\CF@uarrow@radius{0.333}}
    {\def\CF@uarrow@radius{#4}}%
    \CF@ifempty{#5}%
    {\def\CF@uarrow@absangle{60}}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF@uarrow@absangle{abs(#5)}}
    %
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,delta angle=\CF@uarrow@absangle]node(uarrow@start){};
    %
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-CF]}% <---------- `-CF` instead of `-`
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@uarrow@radius,%
    start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF@uarrow@absangle]%
    node(uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@str{\CF@uarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \ifdim\CF@uarrow@radius pt>\z@
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@end}%
    \else
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#2}{0}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@start}{#1}{1}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@end}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

A demonstration:

[image: arr]

**Full Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\definearrow5{-u>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](uarrow@arctangent){};%
    \CF@ifempty{#4}
    {\def\CF@uarrow@radius{0.333}}
    {\def\CF@uarrow@radius{#4}}%
    \CF@ifempty{#5}%
    {\def\CF@uarrow@absangle{60}}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF@uarrow@absangle{abs(#5)}}
    %
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,delta angle=\CF@uarrow@absangle]node(uarrow@start){};
    %
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@uarrow@radius,%
    start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF@uarrow@absangle]%
    node(uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@str{\CF@uarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \ifdim\CF@uarrow@radius pt>\z@
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@end}%
    \else
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#2}{0}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@start}{#1}{1}\CF@tmp@str{uarrow@end}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
%       \schemedebug{true} % Activate if you want to see the nodes etc.
        \schemestart
        \arrow{-u>[$x$][$y$][][.5][]}
        \schemestop
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's still an issue with the `-X>` type arrow in that it doesn't inherit the default arrows settings: I use`\setarrowdefault{,,line width=0.06642em}` (from [here](https://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/)). Can you please point me out to the cause of such behaviour?
Your solution, on the other hand, works flawlessly.

Comment: I haven't got the time now to write a thorough answer, but focus on the `\edef`'s in the `-X>` arrow's definitions. The OP did not load the `\CF@arrow@current@style` after the `\ifempty...\fi` statement. So the resultant arrows will not know of any changes to the default arrow style.

Comment: @ArchStanton I would recommend sticking to the code 'style' from the chemfig documentation though, so all the bases are covered (e.g. otherwise arrow styles not inherited, like you said). I might attempt to post an updated solution for `-X>` in the [first link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125761/117534) sometime in the future. It'll just be an extension of my above code to take 3 more arguments.

Comment: @ArchStanton I've made an update to `-X>` (the version with 9 (!!) arguments) to accept arrow default settings, as promised. Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372947/117534

Comment: This works wonderfully when I try it on Overleaf, but for whatever reason does not work on my own computer (TeXLive 2019). Do you know what could be wrong ?

Comment: @johnymm not sure, sorry. you might have better luck if you ask a new question

Comment: @Troy I did. It turns out that chemfig has changed the private char from @ to _. So you might want to update your answer. My question is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507442/chemfig-upside-down-u-arrow-not-working-in-texlive-2019/507444#507444