# PGF decorations not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, pgfkeys, decorations, pgf-decorations

I am trying to use the following custom `pgfdecoration` to draw bonds with varying length of the double bond while using `chemfig`. The code was obtained from the following link: [How to alter the bond length of a double bond in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148310/how-to-alter-the-bond-length-of-a-double-bond-in-chemfig). However, I am unable to run the code after recently installing `MikTeX` and executing the code throws the following error message: `Undefined control sequence. ...]--[::-60,,,,,rsdbond={120}{120}]-[::-60]}`. I have tried updating `pgf` and `chemfig` from the `MikTeX` console but to no avail.

Does someone know what package I am missing and how to successfully execute this code (see below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\mystartshorten
\newdimen\myendshorten
\mystartshorten0pt
\myendshorten0pt
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sdbond}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {
    {
      \pgftransformyshift{\CF@double@sep}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\mystartshorten}{0pt}}
      {
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\myendshorten}{0pt}}
      }
    }
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}
\tikzset{
  lsdbond/.code 2 args={%
    \tikzset{decorate, decoration=sdbond}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\mystartshorten{\CF@double@sep*cot((#1)/2)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\myendshorten{\CF@double@sep*cot((#2)/2}%
  },
  rsdbond/.code 2 args={%
    \tikzset{decorate, decoration={sdbond, mirror}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\mystartshorten{\CF@double@sep*cot((#1)/2)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\myendshorten{\CF@double@sep*cot((#2)/2}%
  }
}
\setchemfig{
    double bond sep=0.4em,
    atom sep=2em,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:60]--[::-60,,,,,rsdbond={120}{120}]-[::-60]}
\chemfig{[:90]--[::-90,,,,,rsdbond={90}{60}]-[::-120]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "protected" character has changed from `@` to `_`, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507444/194703) for a related problem. You'll need to go through the steps indicated in section 10 of the chemfig manual.

Comment: Change `\makeatletter` to `\catcode\`\_11`, `\makeatother` to `\catcode\`\_8`, and `\CF@double@sep` to `\CF_doublesep`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I changed the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` statements to what you suggested. I also looked at the `chemfig` manual, and tried implementing the test code in Section 6 on page 29 for creating delocalized double bonds. But I still get the same error as mentioned earlier `Undefined control sequence...`. The code in `chemfig` manual, however, still uses `@` instead of `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "protected" character has changed from `@` to `_`. You'll need to go through the steps indicated in section 10 of the chemfig manual. Here is what this yields on my updated TeXLive2019 installation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\catcode`\_11
\newdimen\mystartshorten
\newdimen\myendshorten
\mystartshorten0pt
\myendshorten0pt
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sdbond}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {
    {
      \pgftransformyshift{\CF_doublesep}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\mystartshorten}{0pt}}
      {
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\myendshorten}{0pt}}
      }
    }
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}
\tikzset{
  lsdbond/.code 2 args={%
    \tikzset{decorate, decoration=sdbond}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\mystartshorten{\CF_doublesep*cot((#1)/2)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\myendshorten{\CF_doublesep*cot((#2)/2}%
  },
  rsdbond/.code 2 args={%
    \tikzset{decorate, decoration={sdbond, mirror}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\mystartshorten{\CF_doublesep*cot((#1)/2)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\myendshorten{\CF_doublesep*cot((#2)/2}%
  }
}
\setchemfig{
    double bond sep=0.4em,
    atom sep=2em,
}
\catcode`\_8
\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:60]--[::-60,,,,,rsdbond={120}{120}]-[::-60]}
\chemfig{[:90]--[::-90,,,,,rsdbond={90}{60}]-[::-120]}
\end{document}
```

[image]