# chemfig: double harpoon + arched in/out arrow in reaction

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, chemfig

I am trying to draw some complex reaction scheme where some of the reactions have additional in/out compounds akin to the ones in the figure below.

[image]

I am not familiar at all with `chemfig` and sadly, know little of `tikz`. It seems that the ideal way would be to `\definearrow` but I could not find an easy guide on that (see [this post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21350) for example). Alternatively I am trying to use two separate arrows (see below) but I don't know how to change specific arrowheads into harpoons. Also I cannot figure out how to rotate the names of the compounds at the end of the arched arrow (but that is actually another question)

This is my code ad the moment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
...  
\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}[tp]
\schemedebug{true}
\scalebox{1.0}{
    \schemestart[90,0.7]
    \ce{T_oK^+}
    \arrow(t1--t2){->[][][2pt]}\ce{T_o}
    \arrow(@t2--@t1){-U>[][\ce{K+}][2pt]}
    \schemestop
}
\end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own custom arrows. For example like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow2{<=U>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#2}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1)node[midway](Uarrowarctangent){};%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0);%
    \endgroup%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](Uarrowarctangent) arc (-90:-10:.333) node (Uarrowend) {};%
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=2pt] at (Uarrowend.north) {#1};
}

\definearrow2{<=u>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#2}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1);%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0)node[midway](Uarrowarctangent){};%
    \endgroup%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter(Uarrowarctangent) arc (90:10:.333) node (Uarrowend) {};%
    \node[anchor=north,yshift=-2pt] at (Uarrowend.south) {#1};
}

\definearrow2{<U=>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#2}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1)node[midway](Uarrowarctangent){};%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0);%
    \endgroup%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter(Uarrowarctangent) arc (270:190:.333) node (Uarrowend) {};%
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=2pt] at (Uarrowend.north) {#1};
}

\definearrow2{<u=>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#2}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1);%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0)node[midway](Uarrowarctangent){};%
    \endgroup%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](Uarrowarctangent) arc (-270:-190:.333) node (Uarrowend) {};%
    \node[anchor=north,yshift=-2pt] at (Uarrowend.south) {#1};
}
\catcode`\_=8
\begin{document}

%\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
\ce{T_oK^+}\arrow{<=U>[\ce{K+}]}\ce{T_o}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\ce{T_oK^+}\arrow{<=u>[\ce{K+}]}\ce{T_o}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\ce{T_oK^+}\arrow{<U=>[\ce{K+}]}\ce{T_o}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\ce{T_oK^+}\arrow{<u=>[\ce{K+}]}\ce{T_o}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

There may me an easier or more elegant way to solve this problem, but the above code would yield the following result, which is probably what you looked for:

[image]

Note: A version of this response which works with older versions of the `ChemFig` package (prior to v 1.41) is included in the revision history

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. Probably you need to adjust some of my values manually, for instance the distance of the double-harpoon arrows. I just assumed the distance of both to be 2pt, but it may be different actually. Feel free to edit …

Comment: These look great, but I am having trouble getting them to function. The arrows end up looking like [this](https://imgur.com/a/gQqaTVS) - shifted off to the reactant side, and with the equilibrium lines, and arrow heads not showing up. Do you have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Oh - and it pops up many errors -`pgfError: No shape named is known` and undefined control sequences.

Comment: @TaylorScott : you should post a new question and post your set up. I just tested the code above and it still works for me. Perhaps it is a problem of version incompatibilities of certain packages. But it also could be something completely different. Hard to tell without knowing your code.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - The image above is the direct output of runing your MWE via overleaf - it does not seem to matter whether I compile it under PDFLaTeX, LaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX - it seems that OverLeaf just does not like it for some reason, and I had hoped you might be able to shed some light on why. [here](https://pastebin.com/L3V29Qy2) is the raw output log from running your MWE on PDFLaTeX via Overleaf.

Comment: I also tried running the MWE under Kile on Linux and TexWorks on Windows, and both came back with errors - `MWE.tex:584:Undefined control sequence \chemgreek_drop_symbols:` appears under both.

Comment: @TaylorScott  this is very strange, because I did exactly the same: running the above code on Overleaf. What did you name your file? You may not name files that load the `chemfig` package ”chemfig.tex“.

Comment: I named the file `MWE.tex` in all cases as part of my debugging attempts. And yeah - it is weird, it looks like it should work perfectly.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the chemfig package has been updated since this was written, and maybe that has changed it? If you try this in a *new* overleaf document, does it work for you? - it may be that the overleaf file you have is retrieving a cached version of the output; In the meantime, I am looking into the chemfig documentation to try and rewrite this :/

Comment: From the documentation, it appears that the author has completely rewritten how the the package works, and the `@` notation in this answer is no longer functional - I am working on a re-write

Comment: @TaylorScott I did try the above code in a completely new Overleaf document and it worked. But maybe the set up was still not up to date. Sorry for that! And thanks for updating this! 