# Modifying \arrow{-U>} with makeatletter

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

I made a reaction scheme like in the code and modified the \arrow[-U>] so that I can add an additional reactant that catalyses the reaction by \makeatletter. Unfortunately, the text is too close to the arrow and I want some space between it. All my efforts with the usal spacing commands were unsuccesful. Any ideas?
Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \schemestart
        A
        \arrow{-U>[X][Y]}
        B
        \makeatletter
        \chemmove{\node[below] at (Uarrow@arctangent){\textbf{Protein}};}
        \makeatother
        \schemestop
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe `below=1ex` is ok?

Comment: @polyn Sounds like an answer to me...

Comment: @polyn thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For even more customizable arrows look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74763/easy-way-to-write-below-arrow-arrow-u-in-chemfi).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.